# How to make a complicated LINQ query to DB Asynchronous?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

I have a synchronous project which I am currently working to make asynchronous.

I have the following query. It aims to take data for a particular purchase item and then take the last date the item was purchased and in what quantity it was purchased.

```
    private IQueryable<ItemOverviewDto> GetBaseQuery(string userId)
    {
        var query = this.Context.Items
            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
            .Select(x => new ItemOverviewDto()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                ReplenishmentPeriod = x.ReplenishmentPeriod,
                NextReplenishmentDate = x.NextReplenishmentDate,
                LastReplenishmentDate = x.Purchases
                                 .OrderByDescending(y => y.ReplenishmentDate)
                                 .Select(m => (DateTime?)m.ReplenishmentDate)
                                 .FirstOrDefault(),
                LastReplenishmentQuantity = x.Purchases
                                 .OrderByDescending(y => y.ReplenishmentDate)
                                 .Select(m => (int?)m.Quantity)
                                 .FirstOrDefault(),
            });

        return query;
    }
```

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/MiBuena/ListGeneratorAsync/blob/200248e5bbaac1a657ca33c678c9920d2321e4a0/ListGeneration.Data/Repositories/ItemsRepository.cs#L127).

I build up the query and materialize it later on. When I materialize it - I use ToListAsync(); But I am wondering can this part - ".Select(m => (int?)m.Quantity).FirstOrDefault()," also be made async in some way?

P.S. Select returns an IEnumerable not IQueryable so we can not use ".FirstOrDefaultAsync()" right away.

Comment: I'm confused - if you call this using `ToListAsync`, then _the entire query_ is executed asynchronously, why do you need the `FirstOrDefault` part to be asynchronous? Are you experiencing an _actual_ performance problem or just assuming that changing it to async will give better performance?

Comment: That `IQueryable<ItemOverviewDto>` is just a query. How it runs depends on whether you try to enumerate it directly or if you use an asynchronous method like `ToListAsync()`.  There's no reason at all to try to change `FirstOrDefault` to `FirstOrDefaultAsync` because that function is translated to a `TOP 1` clause, not executed by itself

Comment: @DStanley, Panagiotis Kanavos, thank you for your comments. I thought FirstOrDefault could cause some synchronous operations in part of the query. But based on your comments due to ToListAsync() the whole query will run async. DStanley, since you posted first - if you wish, you can give an official answer, so that I can choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a SQL-based Linq (like EF) query, the *entire query* is converted to SQL and then executed. In your example, the `FirstOrDefault` just tells the query generator how to formulate the SQL. It is not running a *separate* query inside the "main" query.

So when you call `ToListAsync`, the *entire query* is converted to SQL and executed asynchronously. There is no need to try and convert the inner queries to async as well.